# page.Y returning the wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery and JS code:

```
$(function() {
  function addMouseEvents() {
    $('img').addClass('close-overlay-active')
    var close_H = ($('.close-overlay-active').height() * 1.2);
    var close_W = ($('.close-overlay-active').width() * 1.2);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      // console.log('move');
      // console.log(e.pageX + " " + e.pageY ); 
      var mouseX = e.pageX,
        mouseY = e.pageY;

      $('.close-overlay-active')
        .css({
          top: (mouseY - close_H),
          left: mouseX - close_W
        });
    });
  }


  addMouseEvents();
});
```

The desired behaviour ofcourse is for the 'x' mark to be slightly above the cursor. That does happen most of the time , but sometimes the 'x' appears below the cursor that is towards the right bottom of the cursor and sometimes `1000px` below the cursor. Why is this happening ? e.pageY seems to be returning the wrong value sometimes Why ?

Can anybody please explain this behavior please ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/r25o2Lmr/1/)**

Comment: Is this all right https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r25o2Lmr/3/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  function addMouseEvents() {
    $('img').addClass('close-overlay-active')
    var close_H = ($('.close-overlay-active').height());
    var close_W = ($('.close-overlay-active').width());
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      // console.log('move');
      // console.log(e.pageX + " " + e.pageY ); 
      var mouseX = e.pageX,
        mouseY = e.pageY;

      $('.close-overlay-active')
        .css({
          top: (mouseY - close_H),
          left: mouseX - close_W / 2
        });
    });
  }


  addMouseEvents();
});
```

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #b0e2ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sympletts-free-sampler/128/circle-close-128.png">
</div>
```

To get cursor exactly in the center, refer this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/r25o2Lmr/3/)

Comment: `mouseY` is't giveing me thr right value ! .. i have no problem with `mouseX`

Comment: What issue you faced while executing above snippet ?